# iCloud Account ID vs. Apple ID

Tags: ios, icloud

Where can I find out my iCloud Account ID (numeric value) these days. I searched a lot and the only information I could find was for iOS 15 which are outdated. The ID seems to be shown nowhere these days.

Btw. I am not talking about my Apple ID.

I remember it used to be shown in the iCloud App or iTunes, but no longer...